# Why do my angular <img ng:src .../> behave different depending on the browser?

Tags: angularjs

My angular page which I reduced to a to a [minimal example here](http://cipher-code.de/tmp/angular/index.xhtml#/img) I tried three different ways to show the same img (just a red rectangle) in the "img"-Page:

- The first image uses the XML-Style Parameter "ng:src" to specify the file location.
- The second image uses the "ng-"-Prefix style
- The third image just uses the src attribute (which I thought will probably not work well (the [documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) says that as well).

In **Firefox** all three images are displayed just fine.

In **Opera** the page shows only the later two images.

**Chromium** refuses to even load the page at all (it says "Error: An invalid or illegal string was specified." on the console). (It works if I remove the XML-Style img).

Why is this happening? Since I believe in XML my preference would be to get the XML-Style Parameter to work in all browsers. Note that I don't care about Internet Explorer.

Archive with my (broken) project: http://cipher-code.de/tmp/angular.zip

Comment: I'm reading the log in chromium's console but you have the minified version of angular. why don't you use plnkr or jsfiddle, so that we can see the whole markup?

Comment: @EduardGamonal: I exchanged the minified version with the uncompressed version of angular. I don't use plnkr or jsfiddle, because I want my document to be parsed as XML an the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml) says "When a document is transmitted with an XML MIME type, such as application/xhtml+xml, then it is treated as an XML document". I haven't found a way in either plunker not jsfiddle to set the application/xhtml+xml Content-Type.

Comment: If you open your Chrome tool, you'll see the following error message: Error: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The provided markup is invalid XML, and therefore cannot be inserted into an XML document. I'm not an expert, but since you're using the ng namespace in the partial, and since it's supposed to be valid XML, then the namespace should be declared in the partial.

Comment: @yankee Could you package all files as one zip, so that we can test it locally to help you?

Comment: @stanleyxu2005: Zip file attached

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XHTML spec outlines [this algorithm](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-xhtml-syntax.html#xml-fragment-parsing-algorithm) that Chrome [does not implement fully](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/master/Source/core/xml/parser/XMLDocumentParser.cpp#500). Chrome returns the error you observe when the XML is not well formed, which is true when the following step in the algorithm is not followed:

> If there is a context element, feed the parser just created the string corresponding to the start tag of that element, declaring all the namespace prefixes that are in scope on that element in the DOM, as well as declaring the default namespace (if any) that is in scope on that element in the DOM.

The result of not following this step means you have to set `xmlns:ng` on the root element of the fragment you are appending (or technically, any element or parent thereof that uses the `ng` namespace)

**Edit after further discussion in comments:** `element.setAttribute` on Opera doesn't do anything if the attribute doesn't exist. AngularJS [has a compatibility fix](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9202767f415c86b837b6e4c97f8e99316ebcfc7d/src/ng/directive/booleanAttrs.js#L392) for this for Internet Explorer. Enabling this fix for Opera solves the issue on Opera as well. A bug is issued with AngularJS [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7398). Internet Explorer and Opera seem to misinterpret [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082) on this.

Comment: Wow, thanks for finding the hint in the source code. So just to make sure: The issue with chromium is that chromium violates the XHTML specification which suggests that this is a bug? I could not find a bugreport on the topic and I'd consider to create one...

Comment: I agree. It is, however, already a "FIXME" so I wouldn't be surprised if it's already tracked internally.

Comment: very very interesting.

Comment: "Internet Explorer and Opera seem to misinterpret the spec" <-- Not sure on this. I noticed that I can also fix this for opera by specifying both src-attributes (src="" and ng:src="what I actually want"). The spec just says "If an attribute with that name is already present in the element, its value is changed to be that of the value parameter". It does not say anything about namespaces. And there IS an attribute named src, it's just the wrong namespace.

Comment: The fact that Internet Explorer does *nothing* means it must misinterpret one way or the other: 1) it may consider `src` a new attribute, which means it should create one 2) it may consider `src` the same as `ng:src` (`setAttribute` is not namespace-aware like `setAttributeNs` is), which means it should overwrite it. Doing nothing is wrong either way!

Comment: @stevuu: I don't know if IE really does *nothing* or it just does nothing with visual effect. On Opera it is the later - Opera overwrites the ng:src attribute (can be seen in developer tools, but it obviously has no effect). Maybe it's the same for IE.

Comment: That makes sense. It is unclear from the specs if, when using `setAttribute` (in contrast to `setAttributeNs`), `ng:src` should be considered the same as `src`. To me, it feels `ng:src`'s name is `src` so using namespace-unaware `*attribute` calls should consider them the same. Perhaps the different browsers interpret them differently in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome appears to be quite strict when injecting fragments of XML into an XML document, with regards to namespaces. Your partial of images

```
<section>
  <h1>Img</h1>
  <p>With ng:src: <img ng:src="{{img}}" /></p>
  <p>With ng-src: <img ng-src="{{img}}" /></p>
  <p>With src: <img src="{{img}}" /></p>
  <p>As link: <a href="{{img}}">Go to img</a></p>
</section>
```

is using the `ng` namespace, but it's not declared. The following fixes it in Chrome

```
<section xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
  <h1>Img</h1>
  <p>With ng:src: <img ng:src="{{img}}" /></p>
  <p>With ng-src: <img ng-src="{{img}}" /></p>
  <p>With src: <img src="{{img}}" /></p>
  <p>As link: <a href="{{img}}">Go to img</a></p>
</section>
```

Alas not sure why it then doesn't work in Opera.

Edit:

After a bit more testing, it looks like Opera can't quite cope with attributes `src` and `ng:src` on the same element. A solution is to roll your own `ngSrc` directive, called something like `myImgsrc`,

```
myModule.directive('myImgsrc', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('myImgsrc', function(src) {
        attrs.$set('src', src);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Used as:

```
<img my:imgsrc="{{img}}" />
```

(Remembering to properly declare the namespace `xmlns:my="http://mydomain.com"` in both the document and the partial, so as not to break Chrome)

Comment: Your version of `myImgsrc` is the same as [AngularJS's version](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/booleanAttrs.js#L382), except not using `attrs.$set` which accepts interpolation.

Comment: @stevuu: Thanks to you I noticed the [MSIE-Fix in Line 392 of this file](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/booleanAttrs.js#L392). I removed the `if (msie...)` for testing and then it worked in Opera as well without a custom directive. I created [a new issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7398)

Comment: Interesting, @yankee! Keeping track of your issue.

Comment: @stevuu Using `attrs.$set` seems to work just as well, and you're right it's consistent with how Angular does it in `ngSrc`, so I've changed it in the answer. I have to admit, I'm not sure what you mean by "accepts interpolation" though...

Comment: @MichalCharemza: Thanks a lot, your example code for chrome was very helpful and without your testing on Opera I'd probably never figure out what was wrong there. However I also love how stevuu goes to the spec, so I'll accept his answer.